# Javascript img onclick is not having any effect?

Tags: javascript, html, web

So I have a bit of code that is supposed to increment by 1 in an empty paragraph everytime the `up` arrow is clicked. I'm using Javascript but the `onclick` event handler doesn't seem to work:

```html
<head>

  <script>
    var incremented = 0;

    function myfunction() {
      document.getElementById("uparrow").innerHTML = incremented + 1;
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <img id="uparrow" src="uparrow.png" alt="Up" onclick="myfunction()">
  <p id="incremented></p>
    </body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("uparrow")` should be `document.getElementById("incremented")`

Comment: And you never increment the `incremented` varable.  Add something like `incremented = incremented + 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss typed something. You need to insert new value into the `incremented` element, not into `uparrow`. And also increment your value every time.

```css
img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>

<script> 
    var value = 0;

    function myIncrementfunction(){
       document.getElementById("incremented").innerHTML = ++value;
    }
    
    function myDecrementfunction(){
      document.getElementById("incremented").innerHTML = --value;
    }
    
</script>

</head>

<body>
<img id="uparrow" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-c-128.png" alt="Up" onclick="myIncrementfunction()">
<img id="downarrow" src="http://iconizer.net/files/DefaultIcon_ver_0.11/orig/arrow-alt-down.png" alt="Up" onclick="myDecrementfunction()">
<p id="incremented">0</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, however what if i want to add another "down" arrow that does -1 everytime it clicks?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong selector. and you need to increment every time onclick.

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <img id="uparrow" src="uparrow.png" alt="Up" onclick="myfunction()">
  <p id="incremented"></p>

  <script>
    var incremented = 0;

    function myfunction() {
      document.getElementById("incremented").innerHTML = ++incremented;
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Probably shorter to just do `++incremented`.